# Suppose we have $X_1,X_2,X_3 \sim Mult(p_1,p_2,p_3)$, what would be a confidence interval for $\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2+X_3}$?

Tags: confidence-interval

Suppose we have $X_1,X_2,X_3 \sim Mult(p_1,p_2,p_3)$, what would be a confidence interval for $\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2+X_3}$? The top and bottom are not independent and so would this need to rely on a delta method type calculation?

Comment: $\frac{X_1}{X_1 + X_2 + X_3}$ is even not a parameter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean a confidence interval for $p_1/(p_1+p_2+p_3)$, the easiest way is to notice that $X_1\sim Binomial(X_1+X_2+X_3,p_1)$, so it's the same as the standard problem of a confidence interval for a binomial proportion